# Print the shortest path to the java console using orientdb

Tags: orientdb, shortest-path

I want to print in the Java console shortestpath between two vertices. I can not print anything or if you have any way to do that would appreciate it.

```
String subquery = "Select shortestpath(17:10, 17:14, BOTH) ";
Iterable<OrientVertex> result = orientDBGraph.command(new OSQLSynchQuery<OrientVertex>(subquery)).execute();
Assert.assertTrue(result.iterator().hasNext());
System.out.println(result);

for (OrientVertex d : result) {
  System.out.println("Shortest path from " + ((OrientVertex) d.getProperty("$current")).getProperty("name") + " and "
    + ((Iterable<OrientVertex>) d.getProperty("$target")).iterator().next().getProperty("name") + " is: "
    + d.getProperty("path"));
}
```

Comment: What version are you using? Can you post your full code and outpu. Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

**Code:**

```
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQL;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertex;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String dbName = "ytrewa";

        OrientGraphFactory dbfactory = new OrientGraphFactory("remote:127.0.0.1:2424/"+dbName, "root", "root").setupPool(1, 50);

        OrientGraph g = dbfactory.getTx();

        try {
            String query = "select expand(shortestPath) from (select shortestPath(#9:0,#9:1,BOTH))";
            Iterable<OrientVertex> res = g.command(new OCommandSQL(query)).execute();

            while(res.iterator().hasNext()){
                OrientVertex v = res.iterator().next();
                System.out.println("rid: "+v.getId().toString());
            }

        } finally { 
            g.shutdown();
        }

    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
rid: #9:0
rid: #10:0
rid: #12:0
rid: #9:1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I tried to do it with your code but nothing comes out. you can put the entire procedure maybe find some error in mine

Comment: I've added the full code. Please note that my query is slightly different from yours.