# Orientdb and shortestpath

Tags: orientdb, shortest-path

I have a problem with getting the shortest distance. 
the query is well done, but I cannot print the output in the java console 
Can somebody help me?

```
        String query = "SELECT shortestPath((SELECT FROM V WHERE vertexID = 1), (SELECT  FROM V WHERE vertexID = 4), 'BOTH')";
        Iterable<OrientVertex> res = db.command(new OCommandSQL(query)).execute();
while(res.iterator().hasNext()){
            OrientVertex v = res.iterator().next();
            System.out.println(v.getId());
            }
```

I got this one on the browser:

[image]

but in the Java console I got this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query in OrientDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039917/query-in-orientdb)

Comment: What do you get in console? Are you getting some error or nothing? Does the query work in studio?

Comment: No. This is myqueryString query = "SELECT shortestPath((SELECT FROM V WHERE vertexID = 1), (SELECT  FROM V WHERE vertexID = 4), 'BOTH')"; the problem is that the result in the browser and java console is different with the same query. The result in the browser is #10:0 #11:0 #9:1 this result is the correct but the result in tha java console is  #-2:1 . I don't understand why

Comment: You have negative rid, because you need to commit the previous operation, and then query for the shortestPath. If you do both creation and selecting at the same time, the select will run simultaneously while edge isn't been created.

Comment: Looks like an exact duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027499/print-the-shortest-path-to-the-java-console-using-orientdb/40031205). Doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    String query = "select expand(shortestPath) from (select shortestPath((SELECT FROM V WHERE vertexID = 1),(SELECT  FROM V WHERE vertexID = 4),BOTH))";
    Iterable<OrientVertex> res = db.command(new OCommandSQL(query)).execute();
    while (res.iterator().hasNext()) {
        OrientVertex v = res.iterator().next();
        System.out.println(v.getId());
    }
```

Hope it helps.